# How Scroll horizontally keeping a middle Fixed :active div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this slider

https://jsfiddle.net/kaffa22/j4s9w2L0/14/

JS

```
var slideIndex = "5";
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function RSC(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("RSL");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

}
```

When you click an image it shows a text below and gets an .active css propety on that image using JS for both.

How do I make that .active fixed to the middle of 5 images and when clicking any other image it moves to the next one o previous?

I can't get acces to +5 as it is now unless I put a scroll below.

I need them to move when clicked and the active to stay always in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to modify the showSlides() function to calculate the index of the middle dot and set the active class on that dot.

```
var slideIndex = "5";
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function RSC(n) {
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
 var middleIndex = Math.floor(dots.length / 2);
 var newIndex = slideIndex + n - 1;
 if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < dots.length) {
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("active");
  slideIndex = newIndex + 1;
 dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
 showSlides(slideIndex);
 }
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("RSL");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
if (n > slides.length) {
slideIndex = 1
}
if (n < 1) {
slideIndex = slides.length
}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
 var middleIndex = Math.floor(dots.length / 2);
 dots[middleIndex].classList.add("active");
 slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

usage:

```
<div class="RSC">
<div class="RSL">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" onclick="RSC(-1)">
    <div class="RST">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="RSL">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" onclick="RSC(-1)">
    <div class="RST">Nulla volutpat aliquam velit</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="RSL">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" onclick="RSC(0)">
    <div class="RST">Phasellus iaculis neque</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="RSL">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" onclick="RSC(1)">
    <div class="RST">Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="RSL">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=5" onclick="RSC(2)">
    <div class="RST">Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis.</div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
```